# matplotlib does not show the image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = Image.open('images/dot.png')
iar = np.asarray(i)

plt.imshow(iar)
plt.show()
```

I have the image called `dot.png` in the same directory but it is not working.
When I start the program no errors detected. It runs fine. But the matplotlib tool not working.

The window look like this:

[image]

Comment: can you provide an example of what iar looks like? just a print(iar)